# echo default select value

Tags: php, html

**Question**

The current script I'm working on has one form to get the location then after that is submitted and confirmed without errors it will allow the next button to be available to the user prior to updating it to the database.

The main reason for this is to update the map, to give the user a chance to change their mind before proceeding.

The problem is, I want to keep the data they've already submitted. By doing this

```
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Country</label>

                                <select class="form-control" name="country" value=<?php if (isset($_POST['locate'])) { echo '"'.$_POST['country'].'"'; } else { echo '""'; } ?> required>
                                    <?php include('includes/country_list.php');?>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" value=<?php if (isset($_POST['locate'])) { echo '"'.$_POST['address'].'"'; } else { echo '""'; } ?> class="form-control" data name="address" data-parsley-required="true" placeholder="First line address, postcode, zip code etc.." data-parsley-trigger="change">
                                </div>
                            </div>                                

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Site Name</label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" value=<?php if (isset($_POST['locate'])) { echo '"'.$_POST['site_name'].'"'; } else { echo '""'; } ?> class="form-control" data name="site_name" data-parsley-required="true" placeholder="//example: Fawley Refinery, Cottam Powerstation.." data-parsley-trigger="change">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The problem is, I don't want to touch the country_list.php I want to select a default value in the  part. However, what I'm currently using does not work.

Comment: When you have multi-part forms, most of the time you want to either save the previous values in session variables or as hidden elements in the following form.

Comment: @Mike this isn't a multi-part. The only thing that changes is the button. What happens here is the first form is submitted, the map is updated then the user can confirm by pressing the next button that shows in the first one's place.

Comment: So are you using ajax then?

Comment: Only thing I can currently think of is the change them all to disabled text-fields and fill the data.

Comment: @mike not currently.

Comment: You want to use AJAX.

Comment: @PHPglue I will probably use AJAX in the future. However, I've had problems in the past when trying to use it on more than one page so hesitate to use it now.

Comment: That's a poor choice, unless you're in a situation where page flashing and scrolling issues don't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is, I don't want to touch the country_list.php I want to select a default value in the part. However, what I'm currently using does not work.

To meet your requirement of not modifying the PHP include, you're going to need JS...Something like the below should work.

NOTE: I'm making the value attribute `data-value` to be valid HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" data-value=<?php if (isset($_POST['locate'])) { echo '"'.$_POST['country'].'"'; } else { echo '""'; } ?> required>
    <?php include('includes/country_list.php');?>
</select>
```

Then, in JS, with jQuery you could do:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var $select = $('select[name=country]'),
        value   = $select.data('value')
    ;
    $select.val(value);
} );
```

Comment: Oh, *that's* what this question was asking. Why would you use javascript for that when you can just do it all in the PHP?

Comment: @Mike, not sure, but his question specifically stated: "The problem is, I don't want to touch the country_list.php I want to select a default value in the part."

Comment: @Mike I didn't want to touch the country list and was hoping for something as simple as setting a value in the select tags. This is the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use javascript at all to do it:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" required>
    <?php include('includes/country_list.php');?>
</select>
```

Then in `country_list.php` you would just have to check if each country equals the value in `$_POST['country']`. I don't know how you have formatted it, but I'm guessing you're looping over an array of country names. If not, maybe you *should* be! Try something like this:

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    echo "<option value='$country' ";
    if (!empty($_POST['country'] && $_POST['country'] == $country)) {
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    }
    echo ">$country</country>";
}
```

Comment: This is the better approach, IMHO, but it doesn't meet req's of OP's question: "The problem is, I don't want to touch the country_list.php I want to select a default value in the part."

Comment: thank you for the answer, but as kevin has said I cannot touch the country_list.php ( or have access to it ).

Comment: @Danny123 Do you know what the format of `country_list.php` is? Maybe there is something in there already that would allow you to select a default value.